# Devise Error Messages - Not sure What to Do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I keep getting this error whenever I attempt to migrate my database that I created for users using Devise.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:457:in `ensure in with_devise_exclusive_scope': undefined method `merge!' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope:0x00000002850230> (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:457:in `with_devise_exclusive_scope'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in devise_for'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:351:in `block in devise_scope'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:940:in `block in constraints'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:816:in `scope'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:940:in `constraints'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:350:in `devise_scope'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:247:in `block in devise_for'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `devise_for'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:410:in `draw'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:8:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: post your `routes.rb`

Comment: here is my routes.rb file

Answer (score 1):

Did you added devise in *routes.rb* file? If you use devise for users, then you should have this line in your *routes.rb*

```
devise_for :user
```

Comment: HI Garbus - thanks for the response. I do have the devise_for: user in my routes.rb file.